# Can chrome app pass a message/communicate with an embedded page?

Tags: google-chrome-app

As far as I know, only chrome extensions can communicate to an embedded page using content scripts. But is there a way to communicate with an chrome app from a specific page?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs explicitly say:

> Similar to cross-extension messaging, **your app or extension** can receive and respond to messages from regular web pages.

So the ["externally_connectable" approach](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#external-webpage) should work, as described in the docs. Note that an event listener for `onExternalMessage` registered in a background page for an app will fire even if app is not open.